# How can I get this chart to render locally? (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, data-visualization, d3fc

I'm sorry if this is incredibly easy/basic, but I'm completely new to D3.js and I just want to get this example loaded so I can try to modify it with my own data.

I'm trying to replicate the following chart from the d3fc library: https://bl.ocks.org/ColinEberhardt/3ce92a3eef9f97ab4700868896414679

I created three different files as per the example:

```
|- index.html
|- chart.js
|- data.csv
```

But then when I try to load `index.html`, nothing appears in the browser. Am I doing something wrong (or not doing / missing something)?

I haven't installed anything, just copied the code into the files.

Thank you!

Edit:

When I try loading [an example that I download directly from the author's github](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/yahoo-finance-d3fc), it looked like this locally:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/POkSl.jpg

When it should look like this:

https://colineberhardt.github.io/yahoo-finance-d3fc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the whole code block and into your index.html file and the script in to the js file and include using the script src path. then declare the chart handler i.e `<div id="chartIdHandle"> </div>` in your html file and pass to the d3.select function i.e `d3.select("#chartIdHandle")`
You can load the data.csv file within the same function 
i.e `d3.csv("file url")` in your if the file is in the local 
directory you can just use `d3.csv("/data.csv")`
Give it a try.

First I changed all script url to https

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@6.26.0/dist/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/custom-event-polyfill@0.3.0/custom-event-polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.8.0/document-register-element.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@5.5.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3fc@14.0.3/build/d3fc.js"></script>
```

Then the chart js file

```
<script src='chart.js' type='text/babel'></script>
```

Give it a try and let me know[image: Loading chart in via Firefox browser]

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately this didn't work :/

But I'm starting to think that I need to install something? I downloaded an entire example from the author (https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/yahoo-finance-d3fc) and when I tried loading it locally it was also blank: https://imgur.com/a/7ok89md

Comment: I have update the answer so you can take look again and try note: Chrome will give CORS though you are loading your file locally.... Maybe it want the file loaded from a webserver or something but i did my on the desktop though but it worked

Comment: No that didn't work either... Tried on both Chrome and Firefox. I'm thinking I need a webserver. Will give that a shot as well. Thanks for helping!

Comment: For the yahoo finance one, theres and error in the babel script, didn't bother to look into it tho... So replace the babel from 
`<script src="lib/babel.min.js"></script>` to 
`<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script> ` 
I test in chrome and it working... [link](https://imgur.com/a/lzw7w5v?) thats the link...

Comment: @Zach Ok Sure give that shot... cos i got both the one from d3 and yahoo finance running well in Chrome after pushing all to xampp server on the local.
And please don't forget to change the babel script as well just in incase it didn't turn out well... Do check the web inspector or debugger should any error occur

Comment: Got it! Turns out I just needed to have a webserver running. Thanks again for your help!! If you add that to your answer than I can mark it as the accepted solution :)

Comment: You most welcome bruh... Thanks to you too.. I have learn something new as well